# Kotlin : Why some code only works within OnCreate of Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, oncreate, applicationcontext

I'm a beginner in dev trying to get my head around some concepts. Could someone awesome please help me the below? It's driving me nuts!!

Please take a look at this piece of code:

```
    val csvRawText = applicationContext.assets.open("sgsraagadata.csv").bufferedReader().use {
        it.readText()
    }
```

This is how I'm reading my csv file that I've imported into Assets. **Can you please help me understand**:

1. Why this code doesn't work (fatal null pointer error) when I run it outside of OnCreate along with my other variable declarations and initialisations?
2. And why it also doesn't work inside a separate class that is not an Activity? I have a separate class called csvFile which I wanted to house this code, and no matter where I put it, it doesn't work.

Comment: Because `applicationContext` isn't intialized until `onCreate()` is called, and can only be called from a Context object.

Comment: @TheWanderer Lovely! thanks :) hopefully one day documentation will be simple enough for us beginner to get this ourselves! Hopefully an AI you can just ask :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because the applicationContext is not initialized before the onCreate() method get called. In other classes you can't get the applicationContext because only the classes who represents a context, like an activity class or a service, returns it to you